# Using a command's output in printf in ksh

Tags: ksh, printf

I am trying to perform the following :

```
printf "Are you sure you want to copy %s (y/n) ? (file bigger than 10 MB) " "$0"
```

It works fine, nevertheless, I would like to display the actual size of my file, by doing something like :

```
printf "Are you sure you want to copy %s (y/n) ? (file bigger than 10 MB : %s) " "$0" "ls -l $0 | awk {'print $5'}"
```

However, I have a failure by doing so.
I guess it is not the right way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

```
printf "Are you sure you want to copy %s (y/n) ? (file bigger than 10 MB: %lu) " "$0" \
  "$(wc -c < "$0")"
```

parsing the output of `ls` is not reliable (and you've forgotten the `$(...)` around it).

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is in some form of shell like bash or ksh.
X is the file (I also supposed it has space in its name)

```
printf "Are you sure you want to copy %s (y/n) ? (file bigger than 10 MB : %s) " "$x" \
   $(ls -ld -- "$x" | awk {'print $5'})
```

should do.

Please note the `$( some code )` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If on a GNU system, prefer to use `stat` instead:

```
printf "Are you sure you want to copy %s (y/n) ? (file bigger than 10 MB : %s) " "$0" \
    "$(exec stat -Lc '%s' -- "$0")"
```

- `-L` makes `stat` follow symlinks.

Comment: Note that `ksh` (as in the question's title) often suggests non-GNU systems. There are a number of different `stat` commands. The `stat -c %s` syntax is specific to GNU `stat`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Nicely done edit. Looks like people in `unix.stackexchange.com` is also strict with `--` :)

Comment: Yes, though unfortunately `--` will not always be enough here. For instance it still won't work for a file called `-`. Which is why I'd recommend to use the _portable_ `wc -c < "$0"` which has none of those issues (that gives a different result for symlinks though and would fail if you don't have read permission to the file). See also `stat -c %s - < "$0"`

Comment: Portability is always something that could cause debate so I'd avoid that. But just to tell, I prefer easier or more practical solutions when they're available on a target tool or system. If something's better I'd use it or propose it even if it's less portable as long as it suffice the requirements. In this instance, I see that `stat` could be better as it may no longer require to read the whole file just to get its size.

Comment: `wc` doesn't read the whole size either if the file is a regular file (in all except old obscure implementations like old busybox ones)